# Prove a particular subset of a group is closed under inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let G is a group, $\phi$ is an automorphism, and $ A=\{ g\in G\mid \phi(g)=g^{-1} \}$. Consider $a \in A$ and $B_a =\{ g\in A\mid ga \in A \}$.

Prove that $g \in B_a$ implies $g^{-1} \in B_a$.

It seems this problem can be solved directly. However, I could not solve it without using centralizer subgroups.

This is my solution:

---

Lemma: $A \cap Z(a) =B_a$, where $Z(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$.

Proof: $g \in B_a \Rightarrow ga \in A \Rightarrow \phi(ga)=(ag)^{-1}$. Also $\phi(ga)=\phi(g) \phi(a)=g^{-1} a^{-1}=(ga)^{-1}$. So, $ag=ga$ and $B_a \subset Z(a)$.

Since $B_a \subset Z(a)$ and $B_a \subset A$, then $A \cap Z(a) =B_a$. $\blacksquare$

$g \in A$ implies $g^{-1} \in A$, and $g \in Z(a)$ implies $g^{-1} \in Z(a)$. Therefore, with using the lemma, $g \in A \cap Z(a)=B_a$ implies $g^{-1} \in B_a$.

---

Now, I am wondering why I cannot solve it using the following way:

$g \in B_a$ implies $ga=ag \in A$. Also, $ga^{-1}=a^{-1}g$. Now, in order to prove $g^{-1} \in B_a$, I only need to prove $g^{-1}a \in A$ or $ga^{-1} \in A$, but I cannot.

Does anyone have another solution or know how to continue this approach?

Comment: Notation: use `\mid` for better spacing around the vertical bar in set definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* essentially do it the second way, withan adjustment:  you have that $g\in B_a\implies ga=ag\implies a^{-1}g=ga^{-1}$.  That's not too hard to get.

Now, we need to prove $g^{-1}a\in A$.  So look at $\phi(g^{-1}a)=\phi(g^{-1})\phi(a)=ga^{-1}=a^{-1}g=(g^{-1}a)^{-1}$.

Thus $g^{-1}a\in A$.  So $g^{-1}\in B_a$.